# метод, который принимает строку и возвращает новую полученную заменой всех прописных букв на строчные

Tags: java

```
 package home1;
 import java.util.*;
 public class char_4 {
 public static void lower(String s) {
  int i = s.charAt(0);
  for (i >= 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++ ) {

  }

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "cp1251");
    System.out.println("Введите строку:");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
    System.out.print("ответ:%d");
    System.out.println(sb);
  }
```

Comment: у меня по методам не очень получается, поэтому прошу помощи

Comment: У String есть методы toUpperCase() и toLowerCase(), первый возвращает строку, где все буквы прописные, второй строчные

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос? Не знаете, как решить задачу? Представьте, что это **вам** дали строку и велели все символы перевести в  нижний регистр. Придумайте, как **вы** будете это делать, шаг за шагом, и опишите эти действия на `Java`. А если мы за вас ваши задачи будем решать -- вам никакой пользы от этого не будет. А нам никакой радости.Ну и может быть стоит книжки почитать для начинающих.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon ему, видимо, задали руками написать аналог, а он совсем не представляет, как к этому подступиться.

Comment: А глянуть сорцы метода toLowerCase()? Или смотреть исходный код - удел слабаков?)))

Answer (score 0):

Строку надо переводить в `toCharArray()`, затем запустить цикл по этому массиву и переводить каждый символ, который имеет тип `Character`  в верхний регистр с помощью `toUpperCase()`. Можно собирать строку с помощью `StringBuilder`, потому что он работает быстрее чем `StringBuffer`  и данные не надо синхронизировать. Или же создать новый массив той же длины. В крайнем случае можно писать в тот же массив по индексу если он известен, если нет то его можно создать используя переменную. Надеюсь теперь понятно как писать имплементацию метода, который будет переводить буквы в верхний регистр.

Ещё один момент, в java строка является константой, поэтому ту же самую строку изменить нельзя, следовательно поэтому и используется `StringBuilder` или же можно использовать конструктор `String(char[])` для создания новой строки.